# Angularjs login cookie works second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

```
    login: function(user, success, error) {
        var s = new session(user);
        s.$login({}, function (u, putResponseHeaders) {
            if ($cookies.user) {
                console.log('cookie set' + $cookies.user);
                user = JSON.parse($cookies.user);
            }
            else
                console.log('no cookie set after login');

            console.log(u);

            $rootScope.user = user;
            console.log($rootScope.user.role);
            success(user);
        }, function () {
            error();
        });
    },
```

when user clicks login, server sets an auth cookie, above function is supposed to handle the cookie and based on its presence supposed to call success(user). Problem is first time user clicks login 'no cookie set after login' is called and cookie is not seen, second time user clicks it is authorized.
chrome can see the cookie set first time user clicks but why can't the angular js code can't see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the cookie hasn't been set yet and available to Javascript.

This is a strange way of doing what you're doing though. Why do you care about the cookie? Shouldn't login return the user object in JSON form and you just use that instead? The cookie should just be there to pass along session information with subsequent requests...

Comment: Thanks, i was following a blog post